# Django i18n doesn't change language

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'm trying to internationalize my Django site with I18N. When I set the language in my template it doesn't change. This is my code:

```
# my flow
PROJECT
- LOCALE
- MYSITE
  - urls.py
  - settings.py
- APP1
  - views.py
- APP2
manage.py

# settings.py
LANGUAGES = (
 ('it', 'Italiano'),
 ('en', 'English'),
        )
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it'
USE_I18N = True
LOCALE_PATHS = ('home/project/locale/',)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( ...
                  'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
                 )   
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (...,
                  'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                 )

# views.py

from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
text = _("this is a text")
...
return render_to_response('index.html', {'text': text,
                         },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 
# index.html
...
{% trans 'Dashboard' %}

# In index.html I change the language and I 
<form action="{{site_url}}i18n/setlang/" method="
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="" />
<select name="language">
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
  <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE selected="selected"{% endif %}>
{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
      </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Change" />
</form>

# urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
      url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="login.html")),
     ....
```

When  I change the language nothing happens. Where am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: How do you change your language? through session vars? or do you use url patterns?:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n

Comment: I use url patterns (I think...). I use the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

    urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',

    )
```

Or (in case you want all your urls translated:

```
    urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',

    )
```

To enable change lang url requests add (make sure this is outside i18n_patterns

```
    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))
```

Comment: Now I try. How can I put the (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')) outside i18n_patterns ? Thanks

Comment: `urlpatterns = patterns('',(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    )`

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried but I get an error when I change language. I get "Page not found (404). Request URL: http://mysite/it/i18n/setlang/". Sorry but i'm little confused..

Comment: Check the Django documentation, you need to use a POST form to change the language:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem when moving from PyCHarm to Linux server. On the local server LANGUAGES setting can be found in the form xx-aa but when we try on the Ubuntu with same config it can only find default language in LANGUAGE_CODE settings.

How can I make all LANGUAGES setup in the LANGUAGES array active under Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: depends on version of django I think we updated and it resolved a lot of langauge issues.